# How to query maximum display resolution from command line?

Tags: xorg, display-resolution

How to query maximum display resolution from command line?

- Is said query possible?
- If possible, how?

Comment: Do you mean like `xrandr --prop`?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend, and different versions of xrandr have different capabilities. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The command `xrandr`, along with some global options, is used to set the size, orientation and/or reflection of the outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size.   Entering

```
xrandr
```

will display the allowed resolutions, ie

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 800×600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 267mm x 200mm
800×600 85.1* +
640×480 75.0 60.0
720×400 70.1
```